# $ctrl object not available in transcluded scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to access the `$ctrl` scope binding of a new `angular.component()` when using `ng-transclude`.

I want to access `$ctrl` in place of a `.controller()` on the page as we're looking to migrate to angular2 down't the track.

There's a plunkr here demonstrating this: https://plnkr.co/edit/M4k7Av8Q2OrMSsvhZjsb?p=preview

Hopefully someone can shed some light! Code below:

```
// app.js

angular.module('test.app', [])

.component('transcludedComponent', {
  transclude: true,
  template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
  controller: function(){
    this.text = 'hello world'
  }
})

.component('regularComponent', {
  template: '<h2>{{$ctrl.otherText}}</h2>',
  controller: function(){
    this.otherText = 'this binding works';
  }
});

angular.element(document.body).ready(function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['test.app']);
});

<!-- index.html -->
<transcluded-component>
  <h2>transcluded text has no $ctrl: {{ $ctrl.text }}</h2>
  <regular-component></regular-component>
</transcluded-component>
```

Comment: component name doesn't match element

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who has the same issue, I just ended up using `$parent` in place of `$ctrl` to access the correct scope. Hacky as hell, but it works.